# pip из get-pip.py

Tags: python, pip

при попытке установить pip из get-pip.py выбивает это

```
Z:\>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23682, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Users\8A6D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb4oyzlda\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\requests\compat.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 915, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 973, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалил питон из стандартной папки и установил туда, где он как-то раз был установлен.

set PATH, и пробовал устанавливать везде, где было воспоминание про питон, и попал.

Comment: Куда? И почему это помогло?

Comment: @dIm0n "Попробуйте выключить и еще раз включить". "Работает? Не трогай!" (с)

Comment: @dIm0n это мне просто ответил на свой ворос

Comment: @VictorVosMottor уже включал выключал работает

Comment: @Алекс ответ должен быть полезен не только вам, но и будущим читателям, столкнувшимся с такой же проблемой